# fluid conceptual

Tags: fluid-statics

[image]

Yes, the force exerted at the bottom of the tank depends on the area of the bottom, the height of the bottom piece and the top piece.

But this seems so insane. Does this hold for ALL constructions? What if I had a $50$ meter pipe the diameter of a test tube and a huge tank at the bottom? Would the pressure still be that great?

I know the formula, but I'm finding it almost implausible in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Your discomfort is widely shared, so much so that this counterintuitive result has been called the "Hydrostatic Paradox." Fortunately, this means that there are many, many explanations that restore one's intuition. Here's one: http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1119/1.880116

Essentially, the paradox is resolved when you notice that the water in the bottom tank exerts an upward force on the ceiling of the tank. This force is exactly equal to the weight of the water that would have been there if your container were just a large cylinder. Since the water pushes up on the ceiling, we must also have the ceiling push down on the water with equal force (or else the whole thing would blow apart).

Comment: If you're still confused about how adding a small pipette of water to the top of a huge tank will noticeably increase the pressure, the key is that in this theory, fluids are totally incompressible. When an incompressible fluid has nowhere to go, any small force is immediately transmitted through it to the entire container. A small force distributed over a large container is equivalent to quite a lot of weight. This is actually sort of how hydraulic pistons work - pushing on the tank side generates huge forces on the thin side.